# Use SizeToFit() on a UILabel with a shadow?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uilabel, shadow, sizetofit

I am having some `UILabel` elements for which a dynamically alter the text. I also add shadows to the labels using `label.Layer.ShadowOffset` and dito color.

When the text of a label has been changed I use `SizeToFit`. Problem: That method does not take into account the shadows - which leads to labels that are too small and the shadows are cut of.

Is there an easy way to fix this, or do I have to manually alter the size after the `SizeToFit` call?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting the shadow on the layer, instead of using UILabel's shadowOffset and shadowColor properties?  I would expect sizeToFit to account for the shadow in that case.

Comment: I should have written ShadowOpacity too, which does not seam to be available directly on UILabel - has to go through the Layer. (at least not through Monotouch which is what I am using).

Comment: In that case, I would subclass UILabel and override `sizeThatFits:` to add a few points to the size returned by the super implementation of that method.  Have this subclass handle setting up the shadow as well.  Perhaps not the easy fix you were looking for, but at least this way all the shadow behavior is encapsulated into one place.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - if no one else has an easier idea I guess that's what I need to do.